# Fix SQL with two left joins with different conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, left-join

I'm trying to write a query that will allow me to get the sum of a column in two different joins but these two joins will have different conditions. For example, I want to sum the "matter_TotalBilled" from records in a different table but I want to be able to control the date range. So below I have this query:

```
SELECT  
SUM(MattersThisYear.matter_TotalBilled) AS mattersThisYear, 
SUM(MattersLastYear.matter_TotalBilled) AS mattersLastYear 

FROM sys_Team 

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT matter_TotalBilled, matter_TeamID, matter_DateOpened 
FROM Company 
LEFT JOIN ClientRelationship ON 
ClientRelationship.clientrelationship_RelatedToItemID = Company.company_ID 
AND ClientRelationship.clientrelationship_SOSRelFile = 'OR' 
INNER JOIN Matter ON 
Matter.matter_ClientID = ClientRelationship.clientrelationship_ClientID 
GROUP BY matter_ID) AS MattersThisYear ON 
MattersThisYear.matter_TeamID = sys_Team.team_ID 
AND MattersThisYear.matter_DateOpened >= '2016-10-1' 
AND MattersThisYear.matter_DateOpened <= '2017-7-26' 

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT matter_TotalBilled, matter_TeamID, matter_DateOpened 
FROM Company 
LEFT JOIN ClientRelationship ON 
ClientRelationship.clientrelationship_RelatedToItemID = Company.company_ID 
AND ClientRelationship.clientrelationship_SOSRelFile = 'OR' 
INNER JOIN Matter ON 
Matter.matter_ClientID = ClientRelationship.clientrelationship_ClientID 
GROUP BY matter_ID) AS MattersLastYear ON 
MattersLastYear.matter_TeamID = sys_Team.team_ID 
AND MattersLastYear.matter_DateOpened >= '2015-10-1' 
AND MattersLastYear.matter_DateOpened <= '2016-7-26' 

GROUP BY team_ID
```

There are two joins here. One is for "Matter" rows between "2016-10-1" and "2017-7-26" (MattersThisYear) and the other join is for "Matter" rows between "2015-10-1" and "2016-7-26" (MattersLastYear).

This query works as long as I only have the "MattersThisYear" join but as soon as I include the "MattersLastYear" join, the "SUM(MattersThisYear.matter_TotalBilled)" changes, even though this is only referencing the "MattersThisYear" join.

My intention is that for each team, I want to return the sum of matter_TotalBilled for matters this year and last year.

What do I need to change in my query to fix this issue?

**UPDATE 1:**

This is the output I get when I run the following query:

```
SELECT team_Name, 
SUM(MattersThisYear.mattersThisYear) AS mattersThisYear, 
SUM(MattersLastYear.mattersLastYear) AS mattersLastYear 
FROM sys_Team 
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT matter_TotalBilled as mattersThisYear,0 as mattersLastYear, matter_TeamID, matter_DateOpened -- made change at this line
    FROM Company 
    LEFT JOIN ClientRelationship ON 
    ClientRelationship.clientrelationship_RelatedToItemID = Company.company_ID 
    AND ClientRelationship.clientrelationship_SOSRelFile = 'OR' 
    INNER JOIN Matter ON 
    Matter.matter_ClientID = ClientRelationship.clientrelationship_ClientID 
    GROUP BY matter_ID
) AS MattersThisYear ON MattersThisYear.matter_TeamID = sys_Team.team_ID 
AND MattersThisYear.matter_DateOpened >= '2016-10-1' 
AND MattersThisYear.matter_DateOpened <= '2017-7-26' 
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 0 as mattersThisYear,matter_TotalBilled as mattersLastYear, matter_TeamID, matter_DateOpened  -- made change at this line
    FROM Company 
    LEFT JOIN ClientRelationship ON 
    ClientRelationship.clientrelationship_RelatedToItemID = Company.company_ID 
    AND ClientRelationship.clientrelationship_SOSRelFile = 'OR' 
    INNER JOIN Matter ON 
    Matter.matter_ClientID = ClientRelationship.clientrelationship_ClientID 
    GROUP BY matter_ID
) AS MattersLastYear ON MattersLastYear.matter_TeamID = sys_Team.team_ID 
AND MattersLastYear.matter_DateOpened >= '2015-10-1' 
AND MattersLastYear.matter_DateOpened <= '2016-7-26' 

GROUP BY team_ID
```

As an example, looking at the team named "Commercial Litigation", the value for "mattersThisYear" is "16261750".

When I run this query:

```
SELECT team_Name, 
SUM(MattersThisYear.mattersThisYear) AS mattersThisYear 
#SUM(MattersLastYear.mattersLastYear) AS mattersLastYear 
FROM sys_Team 
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT matter_TotalBilled as mattersThisYear,0 as mattersLastYear, matter_TeamID, matter_DateOpened -- made change at this line
    FROM Company 
    LEFT JOIN ClientRelationship ON 
    ClientRelationship.clientrelationship_RelatedToItemID = Company.company_ID 
    AND ClientRelationship.clientrelationship_SOSRelFile = 'OR' 
    INNER JOIN Matter ON 
    Matter.matter_ClientID = ClientRelationship.clientrelationship_ClientID 
    GROUP BY matter_ID
) AS MattersThisYear ON MattersThisYear.matter_TeamID = sys_Team.team_ID 
AND MattersThisYear.matter_DateOpened >= '2016-10-1' 
AND MattersThisYear.matter_DateOpened <= '2017-7-26' 
#LEFT JOIN 
#(
#    SELECT 0 as mattersThisYear,matter_TotalBilled as mattersLastYear, matter_TeamID, matter_DateOpened  -- made change at this line
#    FROM Company 
#    LEFT JOIN ClientRelationship ON 
#    ClientRelationship.clientrelationship_RelatedToItemID = Company.company_ID 
#    AND ClientRelationship.clientrelationship_SOSRelFile = 'OR' 
#    INNER JOIN Matter ON 
#    Matter.matter_ClientID = ClientRelationship.clientrelationship_ClientID 
#    GROUP BY matter_ID
#) AS MattersLastYear ON MattersLastYear.matter_TeamID = sys_Team.team_ID 
#AND MattersLastYear.matter_DateOpened >= '2015-10-1' 
#AND MattersLastYear.matter_DateOpened <= '2016-7-26' 

GROUP BY team_ID
```

This value then becomes what I expect it to be, which is "130094".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're trying to put the same column names in two joins, I think you probably want to union them together before joining.

```
SELECT team_Name, 
SUM(MattersBothYears.mattersThisYear) AS mattersThisYear, 
SUM(MattersBothYears.mattersLastYear) AS mattersLastYear 
FROM sys_Team 
LEFT JOIN (
(
    SELECT matter_TotalBilled as mattersThisYear,0 as mattersLastYear, matter_TeamID, matter_DateOpened
    FROM Company 
    LEFT JOIN ClientRelationship ON 
    ClientRelationship.clientrelationship_RelatedToItemID = Company.company_ID 
    AND ClientRelationship.clientrelationship_SOSRelFile = 'OR' 
    INNER JOIN Matter ON 
    Matter.matter_ClientID = ClientRelationship.clientrelationship_ClientID 
    AND Matter.matter_DateOpened >= '2016-10-1' 
    AND Matter.matter_DateOpened <= '2017-7-26' 
    GROUP BY matter_ID
) 
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT 0 as mattersThisYear,matter_TotalBilled as mattersLastYear, matter_TeamID, matter_DateOpened
    FROM Company 
    LEFT JOIN ClientRelationship ON 
    ClientRelationship.clientrelationship_RelatedToItemID = Company.company_ID 
    AND ClientRelationship.clientrelationship_SOSRelFile = 'OR' 
    INNER JOIN Matter ON 
    Matter.matter_ClientID = ClientRelationship.clientrelationship_ClientID 
    AND Matter.matter_DateOpened >= '2015-10-1' 
    AND Matter.matter_DateOpened <= '2016-7-26' 
    GROUP BY matter_ID
) 
) MattersBothYears ON MattersBothYears.matter_TeamID = sys_Team.team_ID 
GROUP BY team_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
SUM(MattersThisYear.mattersThisYear) AS mattersThisYear, 
SUM(MattersLastYear.mattersLastYear) AS mattersLastYear 
FROM sys_Team 
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT matter_TotalBilled as mattersThisYear,0 as mattersLastYear, matter_TeamID, matter_DateOpened -- made change at this line
    FROM Company 
    LEFT JOIN ClientRelationship ON 
    ClientRelationship.clientrelationship_RelatedToItemID = Company.company_ID 
    AND ClientRelationship.clientrelationship_SOSRelFile = 'OR' 
    INNER JOIN Matter ON 
    Matter.matter_ClientID = ClientRelationship.clientrelationship_ClientID
WHERE  matter_DateOpened >= '2016-10-1' 
AND matter_DateOpened <= '2017-7-26' 


    GROUP BY matter_ID
) AS MattersThisYear ON MattersThisYear.matter_TeamID = sys_Team.team_ID 

LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 0 as mattersThisYear,matter_TotalBilled as mattersLastYear, matter_TeamID, matter_DateOpened  -- made change at this line
    FROM Company 
    LEFT JOIN ClientRelationship ON 
    ClientRelationship.clientrelationship_RelatedToItemID = Company.company_ID 
    AND ClientRelationship.clientrelationship_SOSRelFile = 'OR' 
    INNER JOIN Matter ON 
    Matter.matter_ClientID = ClientRelationship.clientrelationship_ClientID 
    WHERE  matter_DateOpened >= '2015-10-1' 
AND matter_DateOpened <= '2016-7-26' 

    GROUP BY matter_ID
) AS MattersLastYear ON MattersLastYear.matter_TeamID = sys_Team.team_ID 

GROUP BY team_ID
```

Try above query.

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. When I comment out the the "MattersLastYear" join, and comment out "SUM(MattersLastYear.mattersLastYear) AS mattersLastYear", I get a value of "130094" for "mattersThisYear" on a specific team. When I run your query, that value becomes "16261750". Just to confirm, I expect it to be "130094" not "16261750". I don't understand why the second join will change this value.

Comment: @Darren Whats the output??

Comment: And what your expected output??

Answer (score 0):

The way you are joining query is not correct. As you are joining sys_Team first with MattersThisYear sub query. There might be possible of having multiple matter_TeamID and if you join MattersLastYear Subquery then you might get wrong result.

For Example: You have below data which is coming when you excute those query individually.

```
Table: sys_Team
Teamid 
1
```

MattersThisYear Subquery

```
matter_TotalBilled, matter_TeamID, matter_DateOpened
100               , 1            , '2016-10-1' 
100               , 1            , '2017-7-26'
```

MattersLastYear Subquery

```
matter_TotalBilled, matter_TeamID, matter_DateOpened
50                , 1            , '2015-10-1' 
50                , 1            , '2016-7-26'
```

Now you joining sys_Team with MattersThisYear based on team_id.

Output after first join:

```
team_ID, matter_TotalBilled   , matter_TeamID , matter_DateOpened
1      , 100                  , 1             , '2016-10-1' 
1      , 100                  , 1             , '2017-7-26'
```

Now above resultset is used to join resultset of  MattersLastYear Subquery.

After joining you will get below result.

```
team_ID, matter_TotalBilled   , matter_TeamID , matter_DateOpened, matter_TotalBilled , matter_DateOpened
1      , 100                  , 1             , '2016-10-1'      , 50                 , '2015-10-01'
1      , 100                  , 1             , '2017-7-26'      , 50                 , '2015-10-01'
1      , 100                  , 1             , '2016-10-1'      , 50                 , '2016-7-26'
1      , 100                  , 1             , '2017-7-26'      , 50                 , '2016-7-26'
```

And you sum it then you will get wrong result.

Suggestion to your query. I am assuming sys_team does not have same team id twice.

1) Use date filter inside subquery. It can increase your performance as well.
2) You can remove  matter_DateOpened from sub query once you included matter_DateOpened inside subquery. 
3) Sum mattere_totalBilled and use group by team_ID
4) Do 1 ,2 and 3 for both subquery. 
5) Now join it.